# SPO External Sharing - authenticated users

Tags: access, external-users, spo

We are sharing a SPO site collection to an external user domain.

When we add the external users to a SharePoint groups, an invitation has been sent to the user using which the user can login to SPO site.

The below article says the invitation is valid for only 7 days.

https://sharepoint.hannahswain.eu/2015/04/01/sharing-with-external-users-why-doesnt-the-user-show-up-in-the-sharepoint-group-immediately/

Is this true?

Is there any way that we can increase this validity period?

Answer (score 0):

The current access invitation to external authenticated users expires after 90 days and you can view that by navigating to  Site settings ---> Access Requests and Invitations